# Debian Autorun service Systemd

Tags: node.js, npm, systemd, debian-stretch

I'm writing a node.js App.

In this directory (`/var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp$`) I have a `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "MCP",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www",
        "build": "browserify ./app.js > ./public/bundle.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "browserify": "^16.2.3",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
        "debug": "~2.6.9",
        "express": "~4.16.0",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4",
        "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
        "i2c-bus": "^4.0.9",
        "influx": "^5.4.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "morgan": "~1.9.0",
        "node-crc": "^1.2.2",
        "nodemailer": "^6.3.1",
        "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
        "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
        "socketcan": "^2.5.0",
        "spi-device": "^2.0.9"
    }
}
```

The app works fine with

```
/var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp$ npm run start
```

or

```
/var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp$ npm start
```

Now I want the app to start automatically after booting.
Therefore I use `systemd`.

```
$ sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/Start_MCP.service
```

.

```
[Unit]   
Description=Start MCP Service   
After=network.target   

[Service]   
User=debian   
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run start  
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp/  
#Restart=on-failure   
StandardOutput=syslog   
StandardError=syslog  
  
[Install]   
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload  
$ systemctl enable Start_MCP.service  
$ systemctl start Start_MCP.service
```

After a few seconds. The service stops.

```
$ systemctl status Start_MCP.service
```

The syslog shows the following lines:

> Oct 20 08:29:52 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started Start MCP Service.
> Oct 20 08:29:59 beaglebone npm[9518]: > mcp@0.0.0 start /var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp
> Oct 20 08:29:59 beaglebone npm[9518]: > node ./bin/www
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: module.js:478
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     throw err;
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     ^
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: Error: Cannot find module 'bonescript'
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Object. (/var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp/bin/www:26:9)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Linux 4.14.108-ti-r137
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start"
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! node v6.17.0
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! mcp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR!
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Failed at the mcp@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mcp package,
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR!     npm bugs mcp
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls mcp
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone npm[9518]: npm ERR!     /var/lib/cloud9/BBB_WebApp/npm-debug.log
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone systemd[1]: Start_MCP.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone systemd[1]: Start_MCP.service: Unit entered failed state.
> Oct 20 08:30:03 beaglebone systemd[1]: Start_MCP.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

What am I doing wrong ?
Why can I run the app with npm start normally but not with systemd service.
Why is bonescript not found.

Many thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
I can't explain why but reinstalling bonescript in the directory
...../BBB_WebApp$ npm install bonescript --save
has helped.